# SVN revert commit on command line and on Netbeans SVN not producing a svn diff file

Tags: svn, ubuntu, netbeans, merge

I try to merge 2 branches from a SVN repository with a working copy on Ubuntu 14.04. I checked out my repository with SVN command line 1.8.8. I use also Netbeans 8.0.2 as IDE to program my project and something for SVN commands. I tried to merge together 2 branches from my project, eg. branches 0.6.3 into 0.6 4. I do the svn on command line like:

```
svn merge -r myrevionrange1:myrevisionrange2 svn+http://path/to/my/project/branches/0.6.3 svn+http://path/to/my/project/branches/0.6.4 path/to/my/working/copy/branche/0.6.4
```

There is no error message... and no change happened. I'm sure that both branches (the one in repository and the working copy) have different code files.

I suspected that there was a permission denied problem. I do

```
sudo chown -R myusername:mygroupname /path/to/my/working/copy
```

and

```
sudo chmod -R a+r /path/to/my/working/copy
```

and so one with a+w and a+x at the top of my working copy. I retried to merge through command line. There is no error message... and no change in the working copy.

I tried to do the merge with Netbeans. The first time I got an warning message who told me that the working copy was not update. I did it. I do another merge and, this time, changes appeared!

But, when I checked for change with SVN command line like

```
svn status
```

at the top of my working copy... there is no modified file... I tried to commit with both command line and with Netbeans... and there is no file who want to be commit.

I also tried to start from scratch, delete my entire working copy, make another merge with Netbeans and commit. But it doesn't work...

I really don't know what's happened. I use to program in Windows OS and try to do this now in Linux. I work a couple of year in Linux, but spent the last years with Windows, and now, I go back to Linux. I work on new computer with a fresh Ubuntu installation. If someone can help me, please post.

Comment: What is `svn+http`? :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Let me explain the problem. I found the answer. It's not a Netbeans, nor a Linux problem, but a misunderstood of SVN command line.

I would like to revert a commit. I did this command... who seems to do the job:

```
svn update -r RevisionWhereMyCodeIsGood /path/to/the/file
```

The code of this file revert... But I couldn't commit it, nor get a svn status indicating that there was a changed file!

I googled this evening "SVN revert commit" and got another command on this web site:

[How do I revert an SVN commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13330011/how-to-revert-an-svn-commit)

I did the first command line:

```
svn merge -r HEAD:RevisionWhereMyCodeIsGood /path/to/the/file
```

and now, I could get a svn diff, a svn status (Modified) and commit it!

Hope that my post will help other people with the same problem.

PS: About svn+http://, my web hosting company uses a SSH tunnel to access my repository. I wouldn't write my real tunnel name who is my own created word defined in my subversion config file. Then, I replaced by svn+http://... May be it's wrong... Sorry