# how to revert/delete/undo last two commit to svn mainline?

Tags: svn, revert

I have committed my changes accidentally on mainline. Now i want to revert the last two changes committed to the svn server by me.
It seems "revert" command will undo changes in only my working copy. As of now i don't have any changes in my working copy and i haven't created a branch for this project. I want to revert the commit in the mainline.

I have used:
svn commit -m "message i used"

should I use merge command? But I thought this will create more issue. What I wanted exactly is to delete the commit in the svn mainline.

Please help me with the simple and correct command so that i will not mess up anything else.

Answer (score 2):

This command undoes one revision:

```
svn merge -c -REV .
```

Run it twice to undo two revisions.

Or, if you're using [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net), see [this.](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html)

*[(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13330594/3817111)*