# svn undelete and change status on folders and files

Tags: linux, svn

i want to undelete these files

```
[root@localhost sn_dev]# svn log -v --xml | grep 'action="[D]"' 
   action="D"
   action="D">/branches/sn_dev/mob/assets</path>
   action="D">/branches/sn_dev/mob/javascripts</path>
   action="D">/branches/sn_dev/mob/json</path>
   action="D"
```

i have done

```
svn revert --recursive mob
svn commit -m "readded files"
```

however the files still shows deleted status on SVN...

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`svn revert` command](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.c.revert.html) only undoes local edits (i.e. changes that have not yet been committed).  Since you show the files were already committed, you cannot use that command.

You'll need to [merge the reverse of the revision in which they were committed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13330594/1698557).  If, for example, the files were deleted in revision 89, you'd do the following:

```
svn merge -c -89 .
```

The [`-c` option](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.change) is shorthand, in this case, for `-r 88:89`, and the dash before the `89` will reverse the range to give you `-r 89:88`.  This command means, "merge the changes it would take to get revision 89 to revision 88, into my working copy."  The period at the end is the working copy, and should be the directory those files will be restored to.